# Send webRTC video over RTMP to server for live broadcasting?

Tags: android, video, webrtc, rtmp, android-mediarecorder

I am implementing a live broadcasting in my android app. I am using webRTC for real-time video chat. Now I would like to broadcast live chat to many people.I would like to use Mpeg-DASH.For that video stream can be sent to the server over RTMP and then will be broadcasted using Mpeg-DASH.

So I would like to know how to capture media stream of both local and remote user and then send it over RTMP. I have a working prototype for sending camera captured video to the server over RTMP. But I don't know how to send same media stream to the server which is being used by webRTC. 
Possible solutions

1. Record/Capture screen of live chat and then send it to the server over RTMP.
2. Make server a peer in webRTC and manipulate stream and broadcast it via Mpeg-DASH.

I would like to do it in client side.Is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution for this. i am also trying to find any solution but no success.

Comment: No, not as such. I tried a few things but in vain. Now I am not working on that project anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a WebRTC SFU to forward packets to app, and to covert WebRTC to RTMP. It works like this:

```
android app --WebRTC--> Server -+--WebRTC--> android app
                                |
                                +--RTMP--> live streaming platform
                                +--HLS/DASH--> player
```

Because WebRTC is always encrypted by DTLS, so you should covert the stream by a SFU server, rather than hacking the stream of client.

Please read more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70402692/17679565).